# Caja crashes; blinking desktop icons

Tags: mate, desktop-icons, caja

**Caja -- the MATE Desktop file manager -- promptly crashes** every time I open any folder
containing one or more JPGs or PDFs.

The folder disappears after a second or two -- I don't even get time to try to open a PDF or JPG.

I'm running *Caja v.1.26.0-1ubuntu1* on *Ubuntu MATE 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish* on a desktop workstation.

***What I've done so far:***

1. disabled ALL of Caja's extensions and re-booted. Didn't help.
2. did a complete removal of Caja and associated programs, re-booted, re-installed Caja and (one-by-one) its related apps and libs. Didn't help.
3. made sure all file and folder permissions were correct.
4. removed all unused or unneeded Caja-adjacent programs -- I made all the Caja-related programs identical to the list of caja-related apps that are in my 20.04 install on a separate internal drive, where Caja is working with no problems.

These are the (15) Caja apps currently installed:

caja,
caja-admin,
caja-common,
caja-eiciel
caja-extensons-common,
caja-gtkhash,
caja-mediainfo,
caja-open-terminal,
caja-rename,
caja-seahorse,
caja-sendto,
gir1.2-caja-2.0,
libcaja-extension1
python-caja-common
python3-caja

I've already deleted all these and added them back one by one.

At one point, since I couldn't open PDFs or JPGs in the GUI display, I opened a PDF from the terminal's command-line. This caused the icons on my desktop to blink on and off, on and off, until I rebooted. I've never seen such blinking and I wonder if that might signal something specific about what's going on with the desktop when that happens.

Here are some relevant lines from the .xsession-errors file in my home dir:

```
52 mate-session[1906]: WARNING: Unable to find provider '' of required component 'dock'
 53 Window manager warning: Log level 128: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
 54 Window manager warning: Log level 128: Name com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar does not exist on the session bus
 55  
 56  
 57 (process:2428): accountsservice-CRITICAL **: 14:12:19.660: _act_user_update_from_object_path: assertion 'ACT_IS_USER (user)' failed
 58  
 59 (process:2428): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:12:19.660: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GObject'
 60  
 61 (process:2428): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:12:19.660: g_object_set_data: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 62  
 63 (process:2452): ayatana-indicator-sound-WARNING **: 14:12:19.678: volume-control-pulse.vala:746: unable to get pulse unix socket: GDBus.Error:org.freedes    ____ktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.PulseAudio1 was not provided by any .service files
 64 Failure: No such entity
 65  
 66 (caja:2359): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:12:19.714: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
 67  
 68 (mate-power-manager:2427): PowerManager-WARNING **: 14:12:19.720: Failed to get session for pid 2427: The name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit was not provide    ____d by any .service files
 69  
 70 (mate-power-manager:2427): PowerManager-WARNING **: 14:12:19.787: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode
 71 libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
 72 (node:2808) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(    ____), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
 73 (Use `exe --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
 74 Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x3800008 specified for 0x3800006 (Cantata Fi).
 75 QCommandLineParser: option not defined: "allow-screencapture"
 76 INFO:root:The HUD is disabled via org.mate.hud in gsettings.
 77  
 78 ** (caja:2359): CRITICAL **: 14:12:41.938: caja_bookmark_get_location: assertion 'CAJA_IS_BOOKMARK (bookmark)' failed
 79  
 80 (caja:2359): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:12:41.938: g_file_get_uri: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
 81 sys:1: Warning: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 82  
 83 ** (caja:2359): CRITICAL **: 14:12:44.108: caja_bookmark_get_location: assertion 'CAJA_IS_BOOKMARK (bookmark)' failed
 84  
 85 (caja:2359): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 14:12:44.108: g_file_get_uri: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
 86  
 87 (caja:3571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:12:48.616: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
 88  
 89 (mate-panel:2318): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:21:13.872: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
 90  
 91 (mate-panel:2318): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:22:43.503: gtk_drag_finish: assertion 'GDK_IS_DRAG_CONTEXT (context)' failed
 92  
 93 (mate-panel:2318): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:22:43.503: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
 94 Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2600007 (Authentica)
 95 Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
 96  
 97 (mate-panel:2318): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:26:20.867: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion  'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

**Any ideas about what could be causing the crashes are welcome, no matter how off-the-wall they may be.**  *Thanks.*

Comment: it says something about bookmarks - did you try to delete `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`?

Comment: Yes but that had no effect.

Comment: something else profile-related? can you login as guest or another user?

Comment: Thanks! Will report back in a few days when I get home.

Comment: This problem appears to be NOT profile-related.  I created a passwordless guest account, and the same thing happens in that account - if I click on a JPG file, the folder of JPG files that is open instantly disappears. Something about Caja is messed-up, and it extends beyond my user account.

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED:***

I went into the File Manager, opened the "Preview" tab, and set everything there to "Never."

Then, one-by-one, I "un-Never'd" and re-set to "Always.".

The problem is with the *"Other Previewable Files" -> "Show thumbnails"* setting.

If that is set to "Never", ***the problem goes away**.*

Since I don't need thumbnail previews, I will now keep the "Show thumbnails" set to "Never."

Comment: btw for me it's "Local Files Only" and smaller than 10MB, I haven't changed them

Comment: And you're saying you have no problems with those settings, yes?  I can have "Local Files Only" on all the settings in the Preview tab EXCEPT for "Show thumbnails," which I have to have set at "Never" or I have the same problem.

Comment: how much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have plenty of RAM. From inxi: 
System RAM: available: 125.71 GiB used: 4.78 GiB (3.8%)

Comment: some [not yet detected] problems with the  disk? hdd or ssd?

Comment: The drive that my OS is on is an nvme drive. In any case, the problem is gone for me now as long as I have "Show thumbnails" set to "Never", which I do. Yes, it would be nice to know why I get the problem when "Show thumbnails" is turned on, but at this point it's not a priority for me.